# Align the up-vote and flag buttons on comments with wildly different displayed scores

Tags: bug, design, comments

The comment up-vote and flag buttons aren't aligned properly:

[image: An abridged screenshot of 48-score comments' and 3-score comments' up-vote buttons' and flag buttons' horizontal offset.]

The left edges of the texts are aligned, though.

Can we fix that?

Comment: This bug report was filed 2 years and 1 month ago. I'm voting to close this as "cannot be reproduced" since now the flag and upvote buttons are only shown on mouse hover.

Comment: @clickbait – Now the upvote and flag buttons are shown all the time, not just when hovering over the comment. This bug report is still relevant again after almost 3 years!